# Issues with Swift's Combine framework CombineLatest

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I went through the WWDC video of "Introducing Combine" where it was said that whenever a publisher value gets updated the CombineLatest gets called and updated. But the snippet I created works oddly.

```
class Mango {
    var enableButton = false
    @Published var userName = "admin"
    @Published var password = "poweruser"
    @Published var passwordAgain = "poweruser"
    var validatePassword: AnyCancellable {
        Publishers.CombineLatest($password, $passwordAgain).map { (password, reenterpass) -> String? in
            print("Is Password Same to \(password)? :", password == reenterpass)
            guard password == reenterpass else { return nil }
            return password
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
            .map { (str) -> Bool in
            print("In Map", str != nil)
            guard str != nil else { return false }
            return true
        }.assign(to: \.enableButton, on: self)
    }

    init() {
        validatePassword
    }

    func checkSub() {
        print("1. Is password same? ->",enableButton)
        password = "nopoweruser"
        print("2. Is password same? ->",enableButton)
    }
}
```

When I initialize and call the function checkSub() where the publisher 'password' is updated the CombineLatest does not get called. Why is it behaving oddly?

**Input:**

```
let mango = Mango()<br>
mango.checkSub()
```

**Output:**

```
Is Password Same to poweruser? : true  
In Map true  
1. Is password same? -> true  
2. Is password same? -> true
```

Comment: Remember, computed properties have no state, so `validatePassword` does not retain the cancellable that is returns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like the issue is with memory management. The `validatePassword` cancellable is autoreleased, meaning that the subscription is completed as soon as you create it, since you do not retain it. Make it a property instead of computed property, using `lazy var` and it should work fine.

```
lazy var validatePassword: AnyCancellable = {
    Publishers.CombineLatest($password, $passwordAgain).map { (password, reenterpass) -> String? in
        print("Is Password Same to \(password)? :", password == reenterpass)
        guard password == reenterpass else { return nil }
        return password
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
        .map { (str) -> Bool in
        print("In Map", str != nil)
        guard str != nil else { return false }
        return true
    }.assign(to: \.enableButton, on: self)
}()
```

With `lazy` you are retaining the cancellable which gets released only after the object is released. So, this should work properly.

Comment: We could also declared a variable and assign validatePassword to it
`var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

 init() {
        cancellable = validatePassword
  }`

Comment: Yes you can do that as well. You need to retain the cancellable somehow.